# Cloth Simulation intersects with collision object

Tags: cloth-simulation

- Subdivides plane with about 40 cuts
- applied scale
- Turned self collision on and reduced distance on self and normal collision
- Added subidivsion modifier below and above cloth sim (seperatly) but none helped
- Turned up quality steps to 10 and collision quality to 10

[image]

Comment: Did this help, I've written an answer here for a similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265234/cloth-acting-strange-on-thin-object-collision/265240#265240

Comment: if you add your blend file, we can check it out instead of guessing... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Decrease the distance between the cloth and poles before simulating. Then, under collision on the cloth object, increase the quality to something like 10 or 15. Also, don't forget to enable self collisions.enter image description here[image]

The problem in mid simulation might be because it's the first part to touch the poles/there might be a problem in the vertex group you used as a pin group. On the collision settings on your poles decrease the thickness outer value to something like 0.001 to improve the quality of the simulation. On the cloth object, try increasing the quality steps on the top to something like 10. You can also try reducing the vertex mass if you want.

On each of the collision objects (the rectangular ones connecting the poles) **disable single sided.** Add a subsurface modifier above the cloth modifier with a level of 2 or 3. If you want to, you can also add a solidify modifier above the cloth modifier. Increase cloth quality steps to 20 or 25 (subsurface level 3 would be best) and collision quality to something like 40 or 50. Go even higher on all these settings if it still intersects slightly. The higher the quality steps/collision quality/subdivisions in the subsurface modifier, the more accurate your simulation will be.

Comment: Subdivision to 3. Cloth quality to 10. Collision Quality to 15. Distance to 0.001. Self Collision on but still the same

Comment: @patrick823 Subdivision to 4, cloth quality to 15-20, Collision Quality to 25-30, try the solidify modifier on and off, and disable "single-sided" on the collision objects.